# AngularJS nested ng-repeat doesn't modify model

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to loop through a nested object and use a checkbox to toggle the attribute. I am using nested `ng-repeat` statements. The data displays fine but when I go to save the data, it turns out its not actually modifying the `ng-model` like it normally would. Is there something that I am missing here?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="settings-container">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, category) in vm.graphSettings">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>{{ key | titleCase }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row select-row">
          <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="(id, value) in category">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value">
                <div class="pseudo-checkbox"></div>
                <span class="input-name">{{ id | titleCase }}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the object the above `vm.graphSettings` is reflecting.

```
  graph: {
    general: {
      showLegend: false,
      showNullValues: false,
      showTitle: false,
    },
    xAxis: {
      showLabel: false,
      showXAxis: true,
      dynamicLines: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      showLabel: false,
      showYAxis: false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ng-model` should be the name of a model property, not the value itself:

```
<div class="settings-container">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, category) in vm.graphSettings">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>{{ key | titleCase }}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row select-row">
          <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="(id, value) in category">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                ̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶b̶o̶x̶"̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶"̶>̶
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category[id]">
                <div class="pseudo-checkbox"></div>
                <span class="input-name">{{ id | titleCase }}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```